# Connect to mLab mongoDB database using nodeJS Strapi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab, strapi

I just got started using strapi framework and I would like to use mLab as my mongoDB database, so I go to configure strapi and fill the following details:

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 27017,
        "database": "development",
        "username": "",
        "password": ""
      },
      "options": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The details I get from mLab are:

```
mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@ds047891.mlab.com:41365/myDatabase
```

Here is my final config:

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "ds047891.mlab.com",
        "port": 41365,
        "database": "myDatabase",
        "username": "myUsername",
        "password": "myPassword"
      },
      "options": {}
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to start strapi, I get the following error:

```
DEBUG (2748 on DESKTOP-HAL1ATE): Server wasn't able to start properly.
ERROR (2748 on DESKTOP-HAL1ATE): (hook:mongoose) takes too long to load
```

I think that I did not setup my configuration right, but I can't pinpoint where the problem is. I hope someone could, thanks.

Comment: Hi, if you're still having this issue, can you please email support@mlab.com? We'll be able to help troubleshoot connection issues over private email.

Comment: @tfogo Good idea, I just sent the email.

Comment: I too facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Pierre, on of the creators of Strapi. I tried with the following configuration and it worked well:

`{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "ds135777.mlab.com",
        "port": "35777",
        "database": "myDatabase",
        "username": "myUsername",
        "password": "myPassword"
      },
      "options": {}
    }
  }
}`

Our configurations files look quiet similar.

What file did you updated (`/config/environment/development/database.json` or `/config/environment/production/database.json`)?

Are you sure you entered the correct username and password? Did you try to login to your MongoDB instance through the command line `mongo ds135777.mlab.com:35777/myDatabase -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>`?

**UPDATE**

In version >= 3 for mlab don't forget to specify **authenticationDatabase**

```
"options": {
    "authenticationDatabase": "your_mlad_database_name",
    "ssl": false
  }
```

Comment: Yes it works now, I had a problem with the port but mLab support helped. Thanks for taking the time to help me Pierre, much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, great. Have fun using Strapi!

Comment: could you explaing how did the port mlab support helped...as me too getting the same issue

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial: https://medium.com/@strapi/using-mlab-with-strapi-e3f968a9c530.

Comment: The `Update` is what I was looking for. Please add it to your documentation as this wasted my entire day trying to figure out what's the issue. Also `mLab` was acquired by `Atlas`, so it would be nice to also include a way to connect to `Atlas`